# Javascript, jQuery - rotating divs on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a Javascript beginner and am running into a small problem. I'm trying to get my five divs to rotate visibility as soon as the page loads. Right now they only begin rotating after I hover over each of my image buttons. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--

function toggleDiv(id,flagit) {

if (flagit=="1"){

if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "show"

else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "visible"

else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "visible"

}

}

</script>



</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

if (document.all || document.getElementById){ //if IE4 or NS6+
document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')
document.write('.dyncontent{width: 250px; height: 60px;}\n')
document.write('</style>')
}

var curcontentindex=0
var messages=new Array()

function rotatecontent(){
curcontentindex=(curcontentindex<messages.length-1)? curcontentindex+1 : 0
prevcontentindex=(curcontentindex==0)? messages.length-1 : curcontentindex-1
messages[prevcontentindex].style.display="none" 
messages[curcontentindex].style.display="block" 
}


window.onload=function(){
if (document.all || document.getElementById){
getElementByClass("dyncontent")
setInterval("rotatecontent()", 1000)
}
}


</script>

<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div1',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div1',0)" ><img     src="Images/BAB.com_web_link_10.jpg" width="250" height="100"     STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:400px;"></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div2',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div2',0)"><img     src="Images/SLU_on_the_Road.jpg" width="250"     height="100" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:100px; LEFT:400px;"></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div3',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div3',0)"><img     src="Images/Billiken_Blogs.jpg" width="250"     height="100" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:200px; LEFT:400px;"></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div4',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div4',0)"><img     src="Images/SLU_Chat.jpg" width="250"     height="100" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:300px; LEFT:400px;"></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOver="toggleDiv('div5',1)" onMouseOut="toggleDiv('div5',0)"><img     src="Images/Viewbook_Button_2011.jpg"     width="250" height="100" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:400px; LEFT:400px;"></a>
<p class="desc">

<div class="dyncontent"><div id="div1">Div 1/div></div>

<div class="dyncontent"><div id="div2">Div 2</div></div>

<div class="dyncontent"><div id="div3">Div 3</div></div>

<div class="dyncontent"><div id="div4">Div 4</div></div>

<div class="dyncontent"><div id="div5">Div 5</div></div>

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where the function `rotatecontent` is defined at all. Hos is this supposed to work?

Comment: Oh, wow, that's probably because it's a function I got rid of after it didn't work. I forgot that was in there. Basically it's supposed to rotate the divs on load and also eventually I want to add a function that reveals a certain div on mouseover of a button image.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your JavaScript needs semicolons at the end of lines. Run it through a linter like JSLint to find any other errors.
Also, try using `window.addEventListener('load',rotateContent,false);` rather than `window.onload=rotateContent`

Comment: Sadly I tried both solutions and the script still behaves the same way.

Comment: Would you edit your post with updated code, so we may understand what your script now looks like?

Comment: I actually modified the rotatecontent definition and removed the css styling for the divs and the rotation works now. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // code within ready() will execute
  // after page load

  rotatecontent();

});
```